# Why is my sendgrid template showing differently in outlook versus gmail, etc?

Tags: templates, sendgrid

I kept it simple with images and added my tracking links. I did not use the coding version. It's very basic but still shows differently in my outlook vs gmail.

I have tried using code in certain modules vs images but the result is the same. [View gendgrid preview, outlook & gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIJYn.png)

Answer (score 0):

The email that SendGrid sends to Outlook is the same as the email that SendGrid sends to Gmail.
However, every email client renders email differently. What's allowed and supported in one inbox provider isn't the same as the others.

Make sure to test your emails in multiple inboxes and fix any inconsistencies, before sending it out to real customers.

---

Besides that, I can't answer your question without more information. Can you share your template and add screenshots of the email in gmail vs outlook?

Comment: I added a photo

Comment: One thing I notice in your screenshot is that outlook has the least amount of space in width, which probably causes the images to go underneath each other. I'm not sure how the HTML and CSS works without seeing it.